# How to check whether the Html value is 1 in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

```
home.html

        {% if  stud.scrapper_status == 1 %}
          <td>{{stud.scrapper_status}} --> Started</td>
        {% else %}
          <td>{{stud.scrapper_status}} --> Completed</td>
        {% endif %}
```

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r31gU.png)

If my value is 1 I should get started but for all the value its getting Completed, How to check the value if 1 or not in html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `"1"` not `1` so:

```html
home.html

        {% if  stud.scrapper_status == "1" %}
          <td>{{stud.scrapper_status}} --> Started</td>
        {% else %}
          <td>{{stud.scrapper_status}} --> Completed</td>
        {% endif %}
```